# How to fix Xubuntu 14.04 screen flicker that started after update?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, screen, flicker, xfwm4

Every few seconds the entire screen flickers. This began after updates over the weekend (30-31 August). The machine is a Toshiba Satellite P200D, 2GB, AMD Turion 64X2 running Xubuntu 14.04.

Things I've tried:

- Restart and cold start.
- Display compositing ON or OFF makes no difference.
- Screen refresh is 60 Hz, I get no alternatives to this on the pull down.
  (Note: If I set resolution to any non-native size screen refresh sets itself to 59.8 Hz.)
- After reading forums I tried installing compton and typing `compton --vsync opengl`. No effect.

Comment: I've now tried rolling back from kernel 3.13.0-35 to 3.13.0-34 and the flicker goes away. Under that kernel the refresh rate is shown as 76 Hz for the native screen resolution. But I can't stick with this kernel as many other things don't work.

Comment: Re-installed 14.04 and the flicker stopped. After some hours I accepted the system updates and the flicker came back. Is there a strategy for quickly finding the culprit update? There were ~300 in all.

Comment: Looks like the kernel is the culprit. Avoid 3.13.0-35, either by not updating, making 3.13.0-34 default or using the mainline kernel PPA to upgrade to 3.14+.

Comment: if you have a dedicated graphics driver then remove that driver, and use generic one